# 终有一天 vs. 总有一天 usage

Tags: grammar, vocabulary

So I watched 古装 TV drama, I heard these sentences quite a bit.  But not quite sure the 终 or the 总 they were using.   Which ones are correct?

终有一天我会成功。
总有一天我会成功。

总有一天我会报仇。
终有一天我会报仇。

Comment: I think 总有一天 is more common for me nowaday.

Comment: Both are correct and same meaning. A slightly difference is that "总有一天“ is more usual, while "终有一天" is somewhat literary and traditional.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

终有 --> 终於有 (will finally be)

总有 --> 总会有 (will always be)

终有 stress 'eventuality'

总有 stress 'inevitability' and 'certainty'

Both **终有**一天 and **总有**一天 can be translated as '**there will be** a day'

More example:

人**总有**失望之時 -- All people will **inevitably** have disappointment

人**終有**一死 -- All people will **eventually** die

大家一起想辨法，**总能**解決問題的 -- Let us all think together, we **can certainly** solve the problem

大家一起想辨法，**終能**解決問題的 -- Let us all think together, we'll **be able to** solve the problem **at the end**

Answer (score 2):

All of them are correct.
I partly agree with Tang Ho's answer, which 终 presents finally, and 总 presents always.
But putting them into these sentences, their meanings are the same.
终将 is a more graceful expression when you are writhing Chinese, or doing a presentation. And when we speak Chinese, we usually use 总.
So, when you are writing, 终有一天我会成功 is better. But since 报仇 is not graceful, it is better to say or writhe 总有一天我会报仇.

Comment: their meanings are the same in this context because both 终有 and 总有 have the extended meaning of 'there will be'

Answer (score 2):

总有一天 这一天会在不久的将来到来
终有一天 这一天会到来,可能会来的非常晚